# R trouble finding the table in sql database from a function in DBI package, using with RSQLite and dbplyr

Tags: r, dbi, dbplyr, rsqlite

I have been studying a YouTube video from Andrew Couch about RSQLite, DBI, and dbplyr packages. [Here is the link.](https://youtu.be/zAgTlZUugUE?t=373)

I'm running into an error, however, and I'm not sure what is happening. The YouTube video is a good video but I don't think AC is running into the same issue I am having so I don't think it's diagnosed there.

I first load the libraries:

```
library(dbplyr)
library(RSQLite)
library(DBI)
```

I then rename `mtcars` as `sql_mtcars` and I create a connection to the SQLite database and copy my dataframe to that database.

```
sql_mtcars <- mtcars
con <- RSQLite::dbConnect(SQLite(), ":memory:")
dplyr::copy_to(con, sql_mtcars)
```

I turn it into a table (I guess because I have to?)

```
sql_mtcars_db <- tbl(con, "sql_mtcars")
```

I practice writing a query and then testing the SQL version of the query.

```
sql_mtcars_db %>%
  dplyr::select(car, mpg, wt) %>%
  dplyr::show_query()
```

But here is where I get stuck. Now I'm trying to write the SQL code directly under the
dbGetQuery function from DBI.

```
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, '
SELECT sql_mtcars_db.mpg 
FROM sql_mtcars_db
  ')
```

I get prompted with this error message:

```
Error: no such table: sql_mtcars_db
```

But that's confusing to me because when I run this line of code to call the table:

```
sql_mtcars_db
```

I can see that the table is there in the SQLite database.

[image]

Comment: I just deleted that part - I was playing around with multiple tables, just to practice. I deleted because I don't think it's relevant for the question. sorry for confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table name is `sq_mtcars`- i.e. the `select` statement is for the particular `table` and the connection is already established with the database

```
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, '
SELECT sql_mtcars.mpg 
FROM sql_mtcars
  ')
```

-output

```
  mpg
1  21.0
2  21.0
3  22.8
4  21.4
5  18.7
6  18.1
7  14.3
8  24.4
9  22.8
10 19.2
11 17.8
...
```

---

If there are doubts, list the tables with

```
dbListTables(con)
[1] "sql_mtcars"   "sqlite_stat1" "sqlite_stat4"
```